# Disable PHP Session Log from storing in centos - apache server

Tags: php, apache, session, logging, centos

In my server, session logs are getting stored in /var/lib/php/session/ path. Whenever user logs in, and uses our system, the session logs are getting stored and it's huge data. For 3 users it is more than 100kb. What if 1000+ users login! So I need to disable session logging. How to do this? and if I disable, is there any performance issue will occur? Thanks.

Comment: As of now I fixed  it by changing the value of variable session.save_path as empty in php.ini file. Previously it was `session.save_path = "/var/lib/php/session"`. Now, `session.save_path = ""`. Now no session logs are stored in that path. Is this cause any other problem?